# C fread() one struct

Tags: c, struct, fread

I'm working by 2 hours, I search on Google, but the answer doesn't arrive, so I ask you! Hope in Help of someone. When I try to print my struct, I get  only 1 struct empty (struct is correctly created, filled and stored in a file)

My Struct is this:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    int serial_number;
    char name [20]; 
    char surname [20]; 
    char sex[1];
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yyyy; 

} Person;
```

This is  print_file function

```
int print_file()
{
   FILE *f;

   f = fopen("civil_registry.dat", "rb");

   if (!f)
   {
       error("Error on opening file, should be missing!");
       return 1;
   }

   Person *tmp;

   tmp = malloc(sizeof(Person));

   fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
   int length_of_file = ftell(f);

   while(length_of_file)
   { 
       fread(tmp, sizeof(Person), 1, f);

       print(tmp);

       length_of_file = length_of_file - 64; 
   }

   fclose(f);

   return 0;
}
```

Here print function that work properly (I think):

```
int print(Person *tmp)
{ 
    printf("\n\nSerial Number: %i", tmp->serial_number);
    printf("\nName: %s", tmp->name); 
    printf("\nSurname: %s", tmp->surname);
    printf("\nSex: %s", tmp->sex);
    printf("\nDay: %i", tmp->dd);
    printf("\nMonth: %i", tmp->mm);
    printf("\nYear: %i", tmp->yyyy); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In order to use `fread` correctly, `civil_registry.dat` should have been written to using `fwrite`.  Is this how you created the file?

Comment: `length_of_file = length_of_file - 64; `  should probably be `length_of_file = length_of_file - size(Person); ` (unless the data file really is formatted as 64-byte records). Note also you can't `printf("%s", tmp->sex)` -- Person.sex is a single character, and the printf %s format specifier expects a null-terminated string.

Comment: Yes @FiddlingBits the Bin file was written with fwrite() :D

Comment: @user3121023 Ok also this one fixed!

Answer (score 1):

There is *undefined behaviour* in your code .

```
char sex[1] ;
```

And in function `print` -

```
printf("\nSex: %s", tmp->sex);       //  %s would expect a null terminated string
```

if you enter a character in `sex` then no space for `'\0'` .

So increase its size to `char sex[2]` .

Comment: OK, I try to fix char sex[1], with char sex, but now, compilator give me this:

warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Comment: @user3649959 Why would you use `%c` to read a string ? When you made changed stick to `%1s` for taking input and printing . And wait `int` , did you pass `int variable` to %c` ?

Comment: OK fixed thi warning put '&' in front of it!

Comment: @user3649959 No, just pass `sex` .

Answer (score 0):

@ameyCU
So, I fix all problems that you post! But however I can't read the binary file correctly because I reaad 64 bytes to 64 bytes, and my output is struct with all value to 0 or NULL